# Exits with Code 0 but will not print output?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm scraping something in PyCharm and am looking to just make sure that it is working first before proceeding. The code will not print its outputs, though, to the console after I run it. Here is the code:

Thank you!!!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = "https://www.zillow.com/philadelphia-pa/rentals/?searchQueryState=%7B%22pagination%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22usersSearchTerm%22%3A%22Philadelphia%2C%20PA%22%2C%22mapBounds%22%3A%7B%22west%22%3A-75.2058476090698%2C%22east%22%3A-75.17623602154539%2C%22south%22%3A39.9520661821946%2C%22north%22%3A39.97380838759173%7D%2C%22regionSelection%22%3A%5B%7B%22regionId%22%3A13271%2C%22regionType%22%3A6%7D%5D%2C%22isMapVisible%22%3Afalse%2C%22filterState%22%3A%7B%22fsba%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22fsbo%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22nc%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22fore%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22cmsn%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22auc%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22fr%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22ah%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Atrue%7D%7D%2C%22isListVisible%22%3Atrue%2C%22mapZoom%22%3A15%7D"
page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
lists = soup.find_all('section', class_="list-card-info")

for list in lists:
    title = list.find('a', class_="list-card-addr")
    price = list.find('div', class_="list-card-price")
    info = [title, price]
    print(info)
```

Comment: Perhaps you should try printing: `print(lists)` before the loop. Or better yet, `print(soup)` where you will see what the page is returning. Debugging by looking at the assumed values in your code is usually much more efficient that asking a stackoverflow question.

Comment: Can you properly format your code? If your `print(info)` statement is within the `for` loop and if the `lists` variable is empty (because there are not "section" tags with class "list-card-info"), then you will not see any output.

Comment: Looks like you're getting detected as a bot and blocked by a CAPTCHA.

Comment: Yes the comment of SuperStomer is correct. In the page content you can observe: <h1>Captcha</h1> --><h5>Please verify you\'re a human to continue.</h5>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can bypass the captcha by adding a header to the request:

```
header = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36" ,
    'referer':'https://www.google.com/'
}

page = requests.get(url, headers=header)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html')
lists = soup.find_all(class_="list-card-info")

for list in lists:
    title = list.find('address', class_="list-card-addr")
    price = list.find('div', class_="list-card-price")
    info = [title, price]
    print(info)
```

It should return:

```
[<address class="list-card-addr">Good Food Flats - Student Housing | 4030 Baring St, Philadelphia, PA</address>, <div class="list-card-price">$825+<abbr class="list-card-label"> <!-- -->1 bd</abbr></div>]
[<address class="list-card-addr">Vue32 | 3201 Race St, Philadelphia, PA</address>, <div class="list-card-price">$2,037+<abbr class="list-card-label"> <!-- -->1 bd</abbr></div>]
[<address class="list-card-addr">N40 Apartments, 44 N 40th St, Philadelphia, PA 19104</address>, <div class="list-card-price">$3,221+/mo</div>]
[<address class="list-card-addr">Fairmount North | 2601 Poplar St, Philadelphia, PA</address>, <div class="list-card-price">$1,560+<abbr class="list-card-label"> <!-- -->Studio</abbr></div>]
[<address class="list-card-addr">The HUB on Chestnut | 3945 Chestnut St, Philadelphia, PA</address>, <div class="list-card-price">$1,680+<abbr class="list-card-label"> <!-- -->1 bd</abbr></div>]
[<address class="list-card-addr">Korman Residential at 3737 Chestnut | 3737 Chestnut St, Philadelphia, PA</address>, <div class="list-card-price">$3,800+<abbr class="list-card-label"> <!-- -->Studio</abbr></div>]
[<address class="list-card-addr">2116 Chestnut | 2116 Chestnut St, Philadelphia, PA</address>, <div class="list-card-price">$2,115+<abbr class="list-card-label"> <!-- -->Studio</abbr></div>]
[<address class="list-card-addr">Arrive University City | 3601 Market St, Philadelphia, PA</address>, <div class="list-card-price">$2,200+<abbr class="list-card-label"> <!-- -->Studio</abbr></div>]
[<address class="list-card-addr">Chestnut Hall | 3900 Chestnut St, Philadelphia, PA</address>, <div class="list-card-price">$1,325+<abbr class="list-card-label"> <!-- -->Studio</abbr></div>]
[None, None]
```

Comment: To fix the title, I belive the tag should be 'address' instead of 'a'.

Comment: Totally right! Editing answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm pretty new to scraping so I didn't even think about a captcha blocking the output. How did you realize it was there just looking through the html?

Comment: Yes, if you print the page.contet you will see some headers about captcha and human recognition.